# Can we implement a protocol other than spi on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: gpio, i2c, spi, uart

Pi supports SPI, I2C and UART by default. Can we implement any other protocol like MDIO into it? If yes, how do we do it?

Comment: You can implement any protocol you write the code for!

Comment: Hi @tan45, Welcome back. Long time no see！  How nice to meet you again.  Ah, now let me see see. (1) MII / MIDO is a bit low level, connecting MAC devices using PHY circuits.  (3) It is IEEE 802.3 compliant, so you only need to DIY some pretty standard hardware, following the respective IEEE spec.  (3) Reference: MIDO (Management Data Input/Output) Wikipedia
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Management_Data_Input/Output. Best Regards, Yours sincerely, Ta and Cheers. :)